# How to get image data into arrary by ImageMagicK?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, image-processing, imagemagick

I don't know where to start from.

I want to read an image with ImageMagick in an array.

At this point, there is no error:

```
My_image.read("c:\\a.jpg");
```

I want to put in the array what I have already read of the image data.
And I want to write to a file using the ImageMagick library.

Here is my code:

```
...
master.read("c:\\a.jpg");

Image my_image("640x480", "white"); 
my_image.modifyImage(); 
Pixels my_pixel_cache(my_image); 
PixelPacket* pixels; 
int start_x = 0, start_y = 0,  size_x = 640, size_y = 480; 
*pixels = Color("black");
*(pixels+200) = Color("green");
my_pixel_cache.sync();

...
```

But I can't get the array of `a.jpg`. How to get `a.jpg` image data to an array to modify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize your `PixelPacket`:

```
PixelPacket *pixels = my_image.getPixels(0, 0, 640, 480);
```

then you can modify your image pixel by pixel with a nested loop:

```
int w = 640;
for (int y = 0; y != h; ++y)
    for (int x = 0; x != w; ++x)
    {
        pixels[w * y + x].red = 255; // if MAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=8
        pixels[w * y + x].green = 0;
        pixels[w * y + x].blue = 0;
    }
```

`Magick::PixelPacket` is a `struct` which contains `red`, `green` and `blue` members (plus another one for the 4th channel). Finally, to write changes to disk:

```
my_image.syncPixels();
my_image.write("c:\\temp\\output.jpg");
```

Comment: Is this right? If I want to modify a.jpg then pixels[640 * y + x] = Color("a.jpg");?

Comment: No, you have to modify one pixel at a time, using two nested `for` loops. Please clarify in your question what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I have update, would you please let me know whether that is right or not. Thanks for help me in advance

Comment: Sir, I have accept you. But would you let me know what Is this output correct? it seems like black instead red.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://i.imgur.com/5V2RWwr.jpg - Maybe you are working with `MAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16`, so you have to apply a red value of `65535` to see red 100%

Comment: Yes you are right and best programmer. If I want 8 depth then can i just change the depth value?

Comment: You have to rebuild the library with `MAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=8`, or [download the appropriate version with 'Q8' in the name](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php)

Comment: Thanks so much. BTW, can I use ImageMagicK in MFC not empty console project.

Comment: yes (I have seen your other question, please keep the topics separated)

Comment: Ok. I'll keep the topic. You are the best programmer. If you don't mind, would you please let me know how to use ImageMagicK in MFC?